# Distance along the Path Line in Navmesh Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a huge problem. my college group are going to make an Offline Guide Map System  as our final project using Unity. this system should provide a shortest route from one building to another. along with it are the Meter/Kilometer distance. the Distance should compute by the Pathline, but i don't know how to do it. could someone can help us and provide us a code? for those who are going to respond in my request, Thank you in Advance. it would be a big help for us.

a distance along the Pathline

Comment: The [NavMeshPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshPath.html) that is calculated by Navmesh contains an array of points that make up the path. If you simply add up the distances between all the points you will receive your answer.

Comment: also another problem. we are using two Transform object, not NavMeshAgent. if you have a moment, can you provide us a sample of Code for this problem? hoping for your response. thank you in advance.

Comment: [NavMesh.CalculatePath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.CalculatePath.html) doesn't require a NavMeshAgent. You only need to plug in 2 positions and the Path variable and it will fill it out for you (so long as there is a path). The documentation includes an example code.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to `path.corners`, which marks the world position of each corner along the path.

So if you take them and calculate the Vector3.Distance() between each of them, you have the full distance of the current path.

```
var corners = agent.path.corners;
var fullDistance = 0f;

for (int i = 1; i < corners.length; i++)
{
    fullDistance += Vector3.Distance(corners[i - 1], corners[i]);
}
```